# how to import .refCount() in rxjs / angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've got `angular2-seed`-based angular 2 app. I've got following angular/rx code:

```
this.http.get(...).map((res) => res.json()).publishReplay().refCount();
```

I use

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/publishreplay';
```

to import all operators separately. But it seems there's no file to import `refCount` operator... or I am missing something. I'm pretty sure there should be such file, maybe it's stored in a different location.

The brute force solution, the only I've managed to get working, is very brutal:

```
import 'rxjs';
```

I'm using `rxjs` v5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`refCount` is a [method](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.0/src/observable/ConnectableObservable.ts#L51-L53) of `ConnectableObservable`. It's not an operator that can be added to an arbitrary observable - so there is no `rxjs/add/operator/refCount` file.

`refCount` can only be used in conjunction with operators that return a `ConnectableObservable`.

The `publishReplay` operator returns a `ConnectableObservable`, so to use `refCount` with `publishReplay`, there is no additional import required.

Also, you should be aware that importing `rxjs/add/operator/publishreplay` will not work on case-sensitive file systems, as the file name is `publishReplay`.

Comment: everything is fine, but you didn't write what should I import! :)

Comment: You don't need to import anything else. I've updated the answer. If it's not working, you should include any effected error.

Comment: you're right. BTW, thanks for the tip with file cases, you're right, using Windows.